# Loading data in twig from controller using AJAX in symfony 3.4

Tags: json, ajax, symfony

i am trying to load data in twig from controller using AJAX , 
this is my controller action:

```
    public function ajaxAction(Request $request) {
        $students = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('techeventBundle:event')
            ->findAll();
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || $request->query->get('showJson') == 1) {
       echo "request successfull";
            $jsonData = array();
            $idx = 0;
            foreach($students as $student) {
                $temp = array(
                    'name' => $student->getTitre(),
                    'address' => $student->getDescription(),
                );
                $jsonData[$idx++] = $temp;
            }
            return new JsonResponse($jsonData);
        } else {
            return $this->render('@reservation/Default/ajax.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

this is my twig file :

```
    <!--  test Ajax --->
    <button id="loadstudent">load events</button>
    <div id="student">
        <div id="name"></div>
        <div id="address"></div>
    </div>
    <!--  test Ajax --->
    <script language = "javascript"
            src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    <script language = "javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loadstudent").on("click", function(event){
                $.ajax({
                    url:        '/student/ajax',
                    type:       'POST',
                    dataType:   'json',
                    async:      true,

                    success: function(data, status) {
                        var e = $('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>');
                        $('#student').html('');
                        $('#student').append(e);

                        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            student = data[i];
                            var e = $('<tr><td id = "name"></td><td id = "address"></td></tr>');

                            $('#name', e).html(student['name']);
                            $('#address', e).html(student['address']);
                            $('#student').append(e);
                            alert('Ajax request success');

                        }
                    },
                    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Ajax request failed.');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

let me describe to you the problem , when i  click on the button ("#loadstudent") it shows up the 'Ajax request failed ' alert , added to that if you have seen in my action code i have added  echo "request successfull"; after that :

```
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || $request->query->get('showJson') == 1) {
```

it's not displaying that , which means that it's not getting into the condition ! help please i am stuck in this problem since one week ,

Answer (score 0):

Add a route name in the controller `@Route("/student/ajax", name="get-students")`

Example:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/student/ajax", name="get-students")
 */
  public function ajaxAction(Request $request) {          
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || $request->query->get('showJson') == 1) { 
        $jsonData = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'name1',
                'address' => 'addres1',
            ),
              array(
                'name' => 'name2',
                'address' => 'addres2',
            ),
        );

        return new JsonResponse($jsonData);
    } else {
        return $this->render('@reservation/Default/ajax.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Now, in `$.ajax` send the request to route name `url: "{{ path('get-students') }}"`

```
 <script language = "javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#loadstudent").on("click", function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ path('get-students') }}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: true,

                    success: function (data, status) {
                        var e = $('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>');
                        $('#student').html('');
                        $('#student').append(e);

                        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            student = data[i];
                            var e = $('<tr><td id = "name"></td><td id = "address"></td></tr>');

                            $('#name', e).html(student['name']);
                            $('#address', e).html(student['address']);
                            $('#student').append(e);
                            alert('Ajax request success');

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
                        alert('Ajax request failed.');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Twig file output:

```
Name    Address
name1   addres1
name2   addres2
```